# Issues with do-while loop

Tags: java, do-while

I am just a beginner in java coding i was just writing a simple program : user is given a menu he has to enter number between 1-4 if user enters correct number, required task is done if wrong number is entered,user is again asked for input. Below is my program

```
class menu {
  public static void main(String [] args) throws java.io.IOException {
        int choice;
        do
        {
            System.out.println("HELP MENU: ");
            System.out.println("IF STATEMENT: 1 ");
            System.out.println("WHILE: 2 ");
            System.out.println("DO WHILE: 3 ");
            System.out.println("SWITCH: 4 ");
            choice = System.in.read();
            System.out.println(choice);
        }

        while( choice < 1 || choice > 4);
        System.out.println("\n");
        System.out.println(choice);

        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("if statement is selected");
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("while statement is selected");
            break;

        case 3:
            System.out.println("do while statement is selected");
            break;

        case 4:
            System.out.println("switch statement is selected");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**
+++++++

```
E:\study\javacode>java menu 
HELP MENU:
IF STATEMENT: 1
WHILE: 2
DO WHILE: 3
SWITCH: 4
4
52
HELP MENU:
IF STATEMENT: 1
WHILE: 2
DO WHILE: 3
SWITCH: 4
13
HELP MENU:
IF STATEMENT: 1
WHILE: 2
DO WHILE: 3
SWITCH: 4
10
HELP MENU:
IF STATEMENT: 1
WHILE: 2
DO WHILE: 3
SWITCH: 4
```

what ever user is entering through keyboard ,the code keeps on iterating through do-while loop.i identified the cause by printing the input value and what i found is that input value is taken wrong by the code.Please help to solve this

Answer (score 2):

To read numbers or `String`s, I would recommend you to use a `Scanner` object. Create and instantiate it at the begining of the `main()`:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
```

and call the `nextInt()` method in the `do-while`:

```
do {
    System.out.println("HELP MENU: ");
    System.out.println("IF STATEMENT: 1 ");
    System.out.println("WHILE: 2 ");
    System.out.println("DO WHILE: 3 ");
    System.out.println("SWITCH: 4 ");
    choice = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println(choice);
} while (choice < 1 || choice > 4);
```

**Notes:**

- [`System.in.read()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28%29) is actually returning the `int` value of the character you input. For example if you input `1`, the method will return `49` which is equal to `(int)'1'`
- As I mentioned before, you can use `Scanner` to read `String`s, with the method `nextLine()`.

**Edit:**

**Just** to see that you can use [`System.in.read()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28%29) (you must read the documentation to understand what it does) to read an integer, try this (in a separate file so you don't accidentally modify your code):

```
int i = System.in.read();
System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(((char) i))));
```

Comment: ok thanks yes this worked.But i would like to know why did
choice = System.in.read();
did not worked.Why it was taking wrong input.

Comment: Do you want to know why `Scanner` works? Or why `System.in.read()` doesn't work?

Comment: As @Njol said in his answer, it reads a *[byte](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)* of data and the value returned is an `int` between [0, 255]. `Scanner` provides more flexibility because it has methods to read different types `nextLine()`, `nextInt()`, `nextDouble`, `nextFloat()`...

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you're using InputStream.read(), which reads a byte from the stream, not a character, e.g. if you type '1', read() will return 0x31.

Javadoc of read():

```
/**
 * Reads the next byte of data from the input stream. The value byte is
 * returned as an <code>int</code> in the range <code>0</code> to
 * <code>255</code>. If no byte is available because the end of the stream
 * has been reached, the value <code>-1</code> is returned. This method
 * blocks until input data is available, the end of the stream is detected,
 * or an exception is thrown.
 *
```

Comment: +1 this is the correct answer. The OP should use a scanner as @Christian says and read the input as an int.

Answer (score 0):

`System.in.read()` does not quite work like you think it does.  It reads a character (not an int) and returns a byte value, not a integer.

When a user enters "1", `read()` returns 49, which is the integer byte value for character '1'.  (50 is '2', 51 is '3', etc).

[@Christian's scanner suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21287617/650475) is very good.  I think you should do that instead.

Alternately, you can change your `switch` statement to use 49/50/51/etc, but that's kind of ugly.